# Как в регулярных выражениях на python выбрать абсолютно любой символ?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Есть вот такой код

```
rates[ 'inner' ][ 'Находка' ].HKD = {
                        buy: '80,30',
                        buy_arrow: '1',
                        sale: '81,00',
                        sale_arrow: '-1'
                    };
```

Надо от туда достать всё что между {}. Я использовал

```
'\{.+\}'
```

Но не сработало.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется, задача поставлена неверно, так как  между `{}` могут быть и другие `{` и `}`. Надо достать то, что после `= {` и `};` в конце строки. В таком случае можно использовать

```
m = re.search(r'(?sm)=\s*{(.*?)};\s*$', s)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

[Демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/fF27ln/1) и [демо на Python](https://ideone.com/Z6QKwR), результат

```
buy: '80,30',
buy_arrow: '1',
sale: '81,00',
sale_arrow: '-1'
```

**Подробности**

- `(?sm)` - "включаем" режимы `re.DOTALL` и `re.MULTILINE`
- `=\s*` - `=` и 0 и более пробельных символов
- `{` - символ `{`
- `(.*?)` - захватывающая подмаска №1: 0 и более любых символов, как можно меньше
- `};`  - подстрока `};`
- `\s*` - 0 и более пробельных символов
- `$` - конец строки.

Comment: А почему с findall не работает?

Comment: @Andru У меня [все работает](https://ideone.com/OxHoVz), покажите ваш код.